# What's the run time of calling the size() function for C++'s containers

Tags: c++, string, performance, list, vector

What is the run-time of performing .size() for C++'s list, vector, and String classes?

I believe the container objects have a built in size member that is changed upon the resizing of the container; returning this data member, the process takes constant time.

Comment: The complexity requirements are clearly outlined in the standard and references. For example, [`std::list::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size)

Comment: Do you mean `.find()` or `.size()` your title and question disagree

Comment: The standard says that all containers should have constant time `size()`. IIRC, though, libstdc++'s implementation of `std::list` takes linear time.

Comment: @Brian Yes, [for ABI reasons](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49561). Also, `std::forward_list` doesn't have a `size()`.

Comment: .size() takes O(constant). This function only returns the current size of your data structure and it is incremented by one every time you add an element to it, with a global variable like this: size++. You do not have to worry about resizing these containers unless you are dealing with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(1) if you mean that, for size.

For `std::find` it is O(n) in the number of elements.